# Zooming In/Out instantaneously

Tags: javascript, zooming

How would I set this up so zoom changes instantaneously as you move the dragger?

https://jsfiddle.net/5ek6drwk/6/

[image]

```
  var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
        var w = parseFloat(svg.getAttribute('width'));
        var h = parseFloat(svg.getAttribute('height'));

        document.getElementById('zoom').addEventListener('change',
          function() {
            document.getElementById('rv').textContent = this.value;
            svg.setAttribute('width', w + this.valueAsNumber);
            svg.setAttribute('height', h + this.valueAsNumber * h / w);
          }, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to use `input` rather than `change` since input will call your function after the value of the range slider is changed immediately while change will call it only when the value is committed by the user.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

So try this:

`document.getElementById('zoom').addEventListener('input', ...`